# How do you construct JavaScript array which can be similar to the given example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have to make this addRows method with some data, which needs following construction.

```
data.addRows([
    ['UK', 10700,100],
    ['USA', -15400,1]    
  ]);
```

But i have only this way data coming, how can i make it for above method?

```
  var custom = new Array();
  success : function(msg)
  {
    /* Make this structure
    [
     ['UK', 10700,100],
     ['USA', -15400,1]    
    ]    
    */
    var total = parseInt(msg.total);
    for(i=0; i < total; i++ ) {
      custom[0][i][0] = msg.rows[i].land;
      custom[0][i][1] = msg.rows[i].id;
      custom[0][i][2] = msg.rows[i].id;
    }        
  }
  data.addRows(custom); // does not work
```

Error: (tried 3 examples all return same)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'land' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the format of the data that you start with?  It's easy to convert from one structure to another, but we need to know what both structures are.

Comment: jfriend00: var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

Comment: So you expect us to know the format returned by that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `splice` method can be used to add elements to an array en masse

```
    var arr = ["a", "b"];

    var newItems = ["c", "d", "e"];

    [].splice.apply(arr, [arr.length, 0].concat(newItems));

    console.log(arr.join()); //a,b,c,d,e
    console.log(arr.length); //5
```

---

Or you could add something like this to Array's prototype:

```
Array.prototype.addRows = function(arr) {
    var self = this;
    arr.forEach(function(val) {
        self.push(val);
    });
}

var arr = ["a", "b"];

arr.addRows(["c", "d", "e"]);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    console.log(arr[i]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDZCD/)

Comment: @Google - looks like msg doesn't contain the data you think it does.  I would recommend inspecting it with Google dev tools or firebug

Comment: I did that with console.log(where i have data using msg.rows[i].land and i validated the length also); + i used inspection with         `if ( (msgRow.land === null) || (typeof msgRow.land === "undefined") ) { alert("WARN ME!!") ;  } else { //shows that it has data  }`

Comment: @Google - shouldn't total be `msg.rows.length`?  Maybe you shot past the end of your array and you hitting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Suppose initially

```
data = [
     ['UK', 10700,100],
     ['USA', -15400,1]    
    ]  ;
```

in success handler,

```
success : function(msg)
{
   /* Make this structure
   [
     ['UK', 10700,100],
     ['USA', -15400,1]    
    ]    
   */

    var custom = [];

    var total = parseInt(msg.total);
    for(i=0; i < total; i++ ) {
       custom[i] = [msg.rows[i].land, msg.rows[i].id1, msg.rows[i].id2];
    }  

    data = data.concat(custom);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `push` method:

```
  // `[]` is the same as `new Array`, but slightly faster
  var custom = [];
  var success = function(msg)
  {
    var total = parseInt(msg.total);
    for(i=0; i < total; i++ ) {
      var msgRow = msg.rows[i];
      var customRow = [msgRow.land, msgRow.id, msgRow.id];
      // The push method adds a new row to your array
      custom.push(msgRow);
    }        
  };
  data.addRows(custom);
```

Comment: if ( (msgRow.land === null) || (typeof msgRow.land === "undefined") ) { //never happens  } else { // doing} but still that error